# Integrate exponential function using sympy

Tags: python, sympy, symbolic-integration

I am trying to integrate `e^(-x)` from `0` to `1` using `sympy` but I am getting the following error:

```
ValueError: Invalid limits given: ((exp(-x), 0, 1),)
```

Here is my code:

```
from sympy import *
x = Symbol('x')
exact_value = integrate(exp(-x), (exp(-x), 0, 1))
```

Answer (score 4):

Following [the documentation](https://docs.sympy.org/1.1.1/modules/integrals/integrals.html) the only problem is the tuple you establish as a limit *(exp(-x), 0, 1)*, since it has to be *(x, 0, 1)* following the previously mentioned structure.

So the edited code would be:

```
from sympy import *
x = Symbol('x')

exact_value = integrate(exp(-x), (x, 0, 1))
```

Answer (score 3):

I'm pretty sure you want to integrate over x, not e^-x, so that would be:

```
exact_value = integrate(exp(-x), (x, 0, 1))
```

The results is:

```
1 - exp(-1)
```

Answer (score 0):

The correct way to do this is:

```
>>> from sympy import *
>>> x = symbols('x')
>>> integrate(exp(-x), (x, 0, 1))
1 - exp(-1)
```

Source: [integrate](https://docs.sympy.org/latest/tutorial/calculus.html#integrals)